# Rails Restful-Authentication Plugin fails to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

My clean install of the ***Restful-Authentication*** plugin fails with the following message.

```
undefined method `acts_as_state_machine' for #Class:0x46edaf8
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Note: The ***act_as_state_machine*** plugin is installed

Note: The restful-authentication plugin was installed with the following command

```
script/generate authenticated user sessions --include-activation --stateful
```

Thanks

H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code. I just needed to restart the server. Additionally, I found a great blog post provided information that can be used to extend the vanilla restful-authentication plugin. 
[Restful Authentication(Part 3 of 3)](http://railsonedge.blogspot.com/2008/03/rails-forum-restful-authenticationpart.html)